# Continue loading after IntegrityError

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

In python, I am populating a SQLITE data base using the importmany, so I can import tens of thousands of rows of data at once.  My data is contained as a list of tuples.  I had my database set up with the primary keys where I wanted them.

Problem I ran into was primary key errors would throw up an IntegrityError.  If I handle the exception my script stops importing at the primary key conflict.

try:

```
try:
    self.curs.executemany("INSERT into towers values (NULL,?,?,?,?)",self.insertList)
except IntegrityError:
    print "Primary key error"
conn.commit()
```

So my questions are, in python using importmany can I:
1. Capture the values that violate the primary key?
2. Continue loading data after I get my primary key errors.

I get why it doesnt continue to load, because after the exception I commit the data to the database.  I dont know how to continue where I left off however.
Unforutnley I cannot copy and paste all the code on this network, any help would be greatly appreciated.  Right now I have no PKs set as a work around...

Answer (score 6):

To answer (2) first, if you want to continue loading after you get an error, it's a simple fix on the SQL side:

```sql
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO towers VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?)
```

This will successfully insert any rows that don't have any violations, and gracefully ignore the conflicts. Please do note however that the `IGNORE` clause will still fail on Foreign Key violations.

Another option for a conflict resolution clause in your case is: `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ...`. I strongly recommend the [SQLite docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) for more information on conflicts and conflict resolution.

As far as I know you cannot do both (1) and (2) simultaneously in an *efficient way*. You could possibly create a trigger to fire before insertions that can capture conflicting rows but this will impose a lot of unnecessary overhead on all of your insertions. (Someone please let me know if you can do this in a smarter way.) Therefore I would recommend you consider whether you truly need to capture the values of the conflicting rows or whether a redesign of your schema is required, if possible/applicable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `lastrowid` to get the point where you stopped:

http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.lastrowid

If you use it, however, you can't use `executemany`.

Answer (score -1):

Use a for loop to iterate through the list and use execute instead of executemany. Surround the for loop with your try and continue execution after an exception. Something like this:

```
for it in self.insertList:
    try:
        self.curs.execute("INSERT into towers values (NULL,?,?,?,?)",it)
    except IntegrityError:
        #here you could insert the itens that were rejected in a temporary table
        #without constraints for later use (question 1)
        pass
conn.commit()
```

You can even count how many items of the list were really inserted.

Comment: As I understand it, `executemany` exists because it offers a significant speed increase over python-iterated `execute` commands. So your solution, while it would work, will slow down a huge data import significantly. One solution would be to keep track of the primary keys that have been added in a python set and filter the insertList ahead of time before feeding it to the cursor.

Comment: @PeterMcMahan OK I agree. It's not efficient code. It only "works" as you've said.